# Are all (unbounded) chain complexes over a field bifibrant?

Tags: homological-algebra, model-categories

In his paper [Homological algebra of homotopy algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9702015), Hinich defines a model structure on unbounded chain complexes where

- weak equivalences are the quasi-isomorphisms,
- fibrations are degree-wise surjections, and
- cofibrations are defined by the left lifting property.

Obviously, every object is fibrant. Now assume that we are working over a field $k$ instead of a general ring.

> **Question:** Is it true that in this case every chain complex is also cofibrant?

I believe the answer to be yes, and I have an ugly argument that should prove it (even though I still have to check the details). Is there a sly/elegant way to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Every (possibly unbounded) chain complex of $k$-vector spaces is a (possibly infinite) direct sum of complexes of the form
$$\dots\to0\to k\to0\to\dots$$
and
$$\dots\to0\to k\stackrel{\sim}{\to}k\to0\to\dots$$
and their shifts.

It is easy to show that each of these complexes is cofibrant, and so every complex is cofibrant.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is not difficult to see that when $k$ is a field, then a cofibration is exactly a degree-wise injective map.

The key lemma is the following: a chain complex whose homology is trivial is homotopic to zero.

Comment: Merci Damien ;)