# Are chain complexes with degree-wise infinite direct product still cofibrant?

Tags: homological-algebra, model-categories

A theorem I have seen a number of times is that chain complexes over a field decompose into a spheres and disk decomposition (ref [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456887/are-all-unbounded-chain-complexes-over-a-field-bifibrant)). That is, a chain complex $C$ is a direct sum of the chain complexes

- $S(n)$: a single copy of the field $k$ in degree $n$.
- $D(n)$: a copy of the field $k$ in degrees $n+1$ and $n$ with boundary operator the identity on $k$.

This decomposition is used to show that chain complexes are cofibrant in the usual model structure cofibrantly generated by the inclusions $S(n) \to D(n)$.

What is really confusing to me is what happens when the chain complex $C$ doesn't look like a direct sum in some degree. For example, let $C$ be the chain complex with the infinite direct product
$$C^0 = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} k = k^\mathbb{N}$$ concentrated in degree $0$ with zero boundary operator. Clearly, the direct product should not be isomorphic to a direct sum, but this would imply that $C$ is no longer cofibrant? Am I missing something about the assumptions on the category of chain complexes over a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure linear algebra question. Every $k$-vector space is a direct sum of copies of $k$ by choosing a basis. For infinite products, the basis is just *very* big ([MO/49551](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551)).

Comment: In other words, the "Clearly, the direct product should not be isomorphic to a direct sum" is wrong.